# Unexpected error from a layout page

Tags: layout-builder

I am working with Manage display, but for one of my pages I get an error occurring on the Layout page.

> Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in
> Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\Block\InlineBlock->build() (line 223 of core/modules/layout_builder/src/Plugin/Block/InlineBlock.php).
> Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\Block\InlineBlock->build() (Line: 105)
> Drupal\layout_builder\EventSubscriber\BlockComponentRenderArray->onBuildRender(Object, 'section_component.build.render_array', Object)
> call_user_func(Array, Object, 'section_component.build.render_array', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('section_component.build.render_array', Object) (Line: 90)
> Drupal\layout_builder\SectionComponent->toRenderArray(Array, 1) (Line: 86)
> Drupal\layout_builder\Section->toRenderArray(Array, 1) (Line: 250)
> Drupal\layout_builder\Element\LayoutBuilder->buildAdministrativeSection(Object, 0) (Line: 123)
> Drupal\layout_builder\Element\LayoutBuilder->layout(Object) (Line: 97)
> Drupal\layout_builder\Element\LayoutBuilder->preRender(Array)
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. Support for this callback implementation is deprecated in 8.8.0 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. See [https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725'](https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725%27), 'silenced_deprecation', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}() (Line: 573)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

It has something to do with

> Path: /colors/web/node/1/layout. Drupal\Core\Http\Exception\CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException: The 'configure any layout' permission is required. in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 117 of /Users//Sites//web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php).

Thanks.

[image: Not working with one]

Comment: You need to post more info about what caused the error, what are the installed modules from Layout Builder ecosystem. is it a custom block?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Quoting an exception and showing a traceback isn't asking a question. There are many missing details from the question, which is just saying *I am working with Manage display, but for one of my pages I get an error occurring on the Layout page.* There isn't any way to reproduce the issue without more details. We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access. You need to debug what happens and adds what you find out to the question.

Comment: I would start investigating on why `Drupal\layout_builder\Plugin\Block\InlineBlock::build()` gets a `NULL` value when it's sure to get a class instance. It could be the *Layout Builder* module should simply verify it gets what it expects (and that would be a Drupal core bug that needs to be reported), or it could be another module is wrongly setting to `NULL` an entity object (and it would be a bug in that module). Unfortunately, the backtrace doesn't help in understanding that.

Comment: Yes basically, I am getting an error with Layout where one of the actual page is not working.

Comment: Okay now it works! the front page is a node, the anonymous user role requires 'View published content' permissions.